# How can I have Pandas recognize the structure of my data properly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data saved in ".txt" files. this is how they are stored:
[image: structure of my txt file]

I used the code below to read the data and save it in a data frame object: (no need to mention that I'm using pandas library of python):

```
new_df = pd.read_csv(location, sep='\t', lineterminator='\n', names=None)
```

the problem is that when I get the shape of my data frame with new_df.shape I end up with: (123,1). It does not recognize that the data have 4 columns. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that `sep` are tabs?

Comment: also, are you running on windows or mac .... could make a difference with the line terminator

Comment: @RuthgerRighart  not quite sure. But I have tested the code without specifying the sep and I had the same problem.

Comment: @jscriptor  I'm using windows 10

Comment: maybe it is not `tab` but `spaces` - `sep="\s+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't have `tab` but `spaces` - use `sep="\s+"`

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, your data appear to be in fixed width format.

Try to use [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/io.html#io-fwf-reader) to read your data file:

```py
pd.read_fwf(location)
```

You may pass the `colspecs=...` argument to tell it in which column each of the data are, but the routine is smart enough to figure this out automagically.